# Get button index on click, then click on another button using the index from previous one

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get the index from a `button` inside a `div` with multiple of the same button classes. Once that button is clicked the index is put in a variable and then another type of button is clicked using the index (ordering/number) from the previous one.

I can't really wrap my mind around how to do this. I tried the following but no luck.

```js
$('.tab-link').on('click', function() {
  let tablinkIndex = $(this).index();
  $(".slider-dot tr:eq(" + tablinkIndex + ")").click();
});
```

Comment: Your code should work, assuming the `index()` is returning the value you expect, however this will be determined based on the HTML structure which you've not shown us. Can you please add the relevant HTML (at least a small snippet of it) to the question so we can see a working example of the issue

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use data-index for every element to find and determine indexes